# Internet Explorer Print Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

- I have a grid and a print option in a page, where the grid is having 5
  columns & more than 200 rows.
- Print option is used to print the grid,where each cell in the grid will get
  expanded if the content of the cell is large
- While Printing, a image(logo) will be displayed at the end of the grid.

The problem is,

In IE9, in one particular machine used by a client,

- The cell's in the grid is being in a fixed position, so the contents are getting overlapped.
- The image which supposed to be displayed after the grid, is being
  displayed at the end of each page in print.
- It also printing the about blank page of the browser as the first page.

I have tested in several machines but can't reproduce the issue.
Or Is it related with JS permissions in browser.

If anyone experienced these kind of situation please do suggest me finding the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is regarding with Javascript access permissions, and it is because of running the application from ie9-browser mode in IE10.